# Typescript: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IArgs' -- How to compose two types

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm newish to Typescript.

I'm trying to do the following:  define an object of functions where all object functions take in certain arguments and optionally have other typed arguments.

Am I going down the wrong rabbit hole?  Any help is very appreciated!

```
interface ITaskArgs<T> {
  deal: { id: string }
  genericArgs?: T
}

type Tasks = {
    DEPOSIT: {
      create: <T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
      update: <T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
      complete: <T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
    }
}
  

type CompleteArgs = {
    completeArg: string
}

type UpdateArgs = {
    updateArg: string
}


const tasks: Tasks = {
    // other tasks with other functions
      DEPOSIT: {
        create: (args: ITaskArgs<null>) => {
            // only args.deal available here
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
        update: (args: ITaskArgs<UpdateArgs>) => {
            // needs args.genericArgs.updateArg here 
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
        // other functions
        complete: (args: ITaskArgs<CompleteArgs>) => {

          const { genericArgs, deal } = args
          // how do I get genericArgs.completeArg here?

          return Promise.resolve()
        }
    }
}

const testTasks = tasks

// should pass
testTasks.DEPOSIT.create({ deal: { id: "1" }})
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { updateArg: "4" }})
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { completeArg: "4" }})

// should error because genericArgs is typed as null but passed here
testTasks.DEPOSIT.create({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { failForPassing: "4" }})
// should error because `randomArg` isn't an `UpdateArgs` and `updateArg` not passed
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { randomArg: "4" }})
// should error because `randomArg` isn't an `UpdateArgs`
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { randomArg: "4", updateArg: "5" }})
// should error because `completeArg` isn't an `UpdateArgs` and `updateArg` not passed
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: { completeArg: "4" }})
// should error because `updateArg` not passed
testTasks.DEPOSIT.update({ deal: { id: "1" }, genericArgs: {}})
// should error because `completeArg` not passed
testTasks.DEPOSIT.complete({ deal: { id: "1" }})
```

The error is:

```
Type '(args: ITaskArgs<IArgs>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '<T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>'.
  Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'ITaskArgs<T>' is not assignable to type 'ITaskArgs<IArgs>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IArgs'.(2322)
input.tsx(8, 7): The expected type comes from property 'complete' which is declared here on type '{ complete: <T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>; }'
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBU4GcDWBBKAcywB50A+ZAbwChlkATCOAGwC5rlgGOswpQhZAF86yQhBDRgCAsQD8HdDVE0wATwAOKTLizIAvNTH0AIgFEACgHkAyhg616z5AijNIHMuQAUcIlgcGNj4Ad4AlIaUllAA9gC2wFgQJHAg6uQmzgCumgxwnsjefgFBuqHEEVHIMQlJKWkZWfQICZosEIXF-sRlIXKkFJEG0XGJyanpmS6iovQ0alooAMJtHZADhsYurfHtnRByvPyCKgsa2sgAqnkFhwFbTjm3G0THAiCEZwutIHzIYBCgWQ5X0Rie9AA9JDkLEwAALaAAoHIADuwARsIRSJg2RACDAwFifyyFhs9nQjmazjcHggHBKvTQ5QGJBA2RYLHIw0oEJc-OhsJALHUyB6WAAdExWGKAG5wYAsOAAIw6yER7mp-OQ7jA2SgIBqY3qEvcWFiLFlEB84S1IgANHbcvlCozgcFcKybi77sRudU+dqoTCpBAGPpxRKJFIBLIAhKegAmdXQFB2ly6-WG2rjCCmiDmy3W21Bh12wVwjXIXH4wnErB23b7V3ivqesKrPbrX1Yf0jYzp1z1sCcaPSOPEe2MZgsERbcWDwXw2KoxixNDiTqbmMyAYJogp9zyBal+iZg1GurJfOFq02u1zZyzH7DgEFsCgraAvQLQVYZccgwyCaNgDaQHwoISmSdgYBKtJ3D4VDTqwjhcDwyAAEQAIwYSIwi2uBH5AlBVgwegErOghSHSuwnDcBw2G4cIU5jrGAyoZRryEAxAAsTH4Wo76QdBFIUS81rUTOqH0ZhOEOtu47sZwTbdkcmF8Xhto0H+AEsEB0BxFAgkQcRImwfBkCIchtFITJjHyaxu6lJw8CKgAYrEUCWKBgi8fxBFCaZpGiZxEnWdJ6H2cxClsc5SFQGkDAJGpGEacIAmEcJwWwaFVk0RFDFydFjkTsCSEqQcKVpRlgV6CR5I5eJeVSXRkVFSxkiKXF6UBSZdVmeRFWWZJKGtYV-lAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Second approach:
Just let TypeScript to infer types for You, don't provide types for arguments:

```js
interface ITaskArgs<T> {
  deal: { id: string }
  genericArgs?: T
}

// **UPDATED**
type Tasks = {
    DEPOSIT: {
       create: <T>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
       update: <T extends { updateArg: string }>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
       complete: <T extends { completeArg: string }>(args: ITaskArgs<T>) => Promise<any>
    }
}
  

type IArgs = {
    arg: string
}


type IArgs2 = {
    arg2: string
}

const tasks: Tasks = {
    // other tasks with other functions
    DEPOSIT: {
        create: (args) => {
            // only args.deal available here
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
        update: (args) => {
            // needs args.genericArgs.arg2 here 
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
        // other functions
        complete: (args) => {

          const { genericArgs, deal } = args
          // how do I get genericArgs.arg here?

          return Promise.resolve()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  But I think I need a more dynamic solution -- I'm sorry if I didn't ask the question well enough to start.  I've edited my question to show additional methods `create` and `update`.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works for You

Comment: Thanks!  It passes, but letting it infer it no longer enforces the types.  I've added tests to the bottom of the playground and edited again.

Comment: Could You please explain why bottom tests should fail?

Comment: Updated and explained

Comment: I think it will be useful to make function which returns tasks object. IT might be easier to properly type it.

Comment: I have updated [type Tasks], it should help, I think you will get the idea. My last update is not full, but You should add constraints to the generic parameter. I will take a look tomorrow on this question again

Comment: Thanks!  That would work, but there are many other keys.  The actual typing of the file is ```export type ITasks = Partial<
  Record<
    ITasksAllowed,
    {
      upsert: (args) => Promise<ITaskItem[] | []>
      update: (args) => Promise<any>
      complete: (args) => Promise<any>
      undo: (args) => Promise<any>
    }
  >
>```  Your solution works but requires explicit typing.  But that may be the best way.  I'll think on it too.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure we can define constraints in other way.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I think you're right and I wasn't using generics properly.  Thanks for your time!